# Following "next" link with relative paths using rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using the `rvest` package to scrape information from the page http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts.  After scraping the first page, I want to follow the "Next" link at the bottom, scrape that second page, move onto the third page, etc.

The following line gives an error:

```
html_session("http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts") %>% follow_link("Next")
## Navigating to 
##     
##       ./2/  
## Error in parseURI(u) : cannot parse URI 
##     
##       ./2/
```

Inspecting the HTML shows there is some extra cruft around the "./2/" that `rvest` apparently doesn't like:

```
html("http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts") %>% html_node(".pagefooter-next a")
## <a href="&#10;    &#10;      ./2/  ">Next</a> 

.Last.value %>% html_attrs()
##                   href 
## "\n    \n      ./2/  "
```

**Question 1:**
How can I get `rvest::follow_link` to treat this link correctly like my browser does?  (I could manually grab the "Next" link and clean it up with regex, but prefer to take advantage of the automation provided with `rvest`.)

---

At the end of the `follow_link` code, it calls `jump_to`.  So I tried the following:

```
html_session("http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts") %>% jump_to("./2/")
## <session> http://www.radiolab.org/series/2/
##   Status: 404
##   Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
##   Size:   10744
## Warning message:
## In request_GET(x, url, ...) : client error: (404) Not Found
```

Digging into the code, it looks like the issue is with `XML::getRelativeURL`, which uses `dirname` to strip off the last part of the original path ("/podcasts"):

```
XML::getRelativeURL("./2/", "http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts/")
## [1] "http://www.radiolab.org/series/./2"

XML::getRelativeURL("../3/", "http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts/2/")
## [1] "http://www.radiolab.org/series/3"
```

**Question 2:**
How can I get `rvest::jump_to` and `XML::getRelativeURL` to correctly handle relative paths?

Comment: Install the dev version where this bug is fixed

Comment: Well the second bug is; rvest isn't going to magically repair bad urls.

Answer (score 1):

Since this problem still seems to occur with RadioLab.com, your best solution is to create a custom function to handle this edge case. If you're only worried about this site - and this particular error - then you can write something like this:

```
library(rvest)

follow_next <- function(session, text ="Next", ...) {
    link <- html_node(session, xpath = sprintf("//*[text()[contains(.,'%s')]]", text))
    url <- html_attr(link, "href")
    url = trimws(url)
    url = gsub("^\\.{1}/", "", url)
    message("Navigating to ", url)
    jump_to(session, url, ...)
}
```

That would allow you to write code like this:

```
html_session("http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts") %>%
    follow_next()

#> Navigating to 2/
#> <session> http://www.radiolab.org/series/podcasts/2/
#>   Status: 200
#>   Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
#>   Size:   61261
```

This is not per se an error - the URL on RadioLab is malformed, and failing to parse a malformed URL is not a bug. If you want to be liberal in how you handle the issue you need to manually work around it.

Note that you could also use `RSelenium` to launch an *actual* browser (e.g. Chrome) and have that perform the URL parsing for you.