# Scraping a dynamic ecommerce page with infinite scroll

Tags: r, web-scraping, infinite-scroll, rvest

I'm using `rvest` in R to do some scraping. I know some HTML and CSS.

I want to get the prices of every product of a URI:

http://www.linio.com.co/tecnologia/celulares-telefonia-gps/

The new items load as you go down on the page (as you do some scrolling).

What I've done so far:

```
Linio_Celulares <- html("http://www.linio.com.co/celulares-telefonia-gps/")

Linio_Celulares %>%
  html_nodes(".product-itm-price-new") %>%
  html_text()
```

And i get what i need, but just for the 25 first elements (those load for default).

```
 [1] "$ 1.999.900" "$ 1.999.900" "$ 1.999.900" "$ 2.299.900" "$ 2.279.900"
 [6] "$ 2.279.900" "$ 1.159.900" "$ 1.749.900" "$ 1.879.900" "$ 189.900"  
[11] "$ 2.299.900" "$ 2.499.900" "$ 2.499.900" "$ 2.799.000" "$ 529.900"  
[16] "$ 2.699.900" "$ 2.149.900" "$ 189.900"   "$ 2.549.900" "$ 1.395.900"
[21] "$ 249.900"   "$ 41.900"    "$ 319.900"   "$ 149.900"
```

**Question: How to get all the elements of this dynamic section?**

I guess, I could scroll the page until all elements are loaded and then use html(URL). But this seems like a lot of work (i'm planning of doing this on different sections). There should be a programmatic work around.

Comment: You would need to use XPath (in R or outside of R) -- have a look at the `XML` package.

Comment: It can't be done with Rvest? I've seen that Rvest imports XML. I've read somestuff about XML. But i'm the URL in my example, i don't see this meta tags from XML. May you help me out?

Comment: Here, I think maybe this will help you do it in `rvest`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812259/following-next-link-with-relative-paths-using-rvest

Comment: @Hack-R. I've seen your example, but what i have is a little different. In my example, there isn't a "Next" button or "Page 2". However, i see a :"<div id="page-number">Página 4</div>" (this changes from 2 to X) that activates as i do scrolling.Would be nice if you have any other tip.

Comment: @OmarGonzales You may have to look into `RSelenium` to achieve this - see [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692227/web-scraping-with-r).

Comment: I have been to many links but people redirect finally to selenium,  How on earth it is not possible in rvest or any R package to activate an infinite scroll page and scrape the final scroll included? Could we invoke @hadley to help here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As @nrussell suggested, you can use `RSelenium` to programatically scroll down the page before getting the source code.

You could for example do:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
#start RSelenium
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("http://www.linio.com.co/tecnologia/celulares-telefonia-gps/")

#scroll down 5 times, waiting for the page to load at each time
for(i in 1:5){      
remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");"))
Sys.sleep(3)    
}

#get the page html
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()

#parse it
html(page_source[[1]]) %>% html_nodes(".product-itm-price-new") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: i've been learning some Javascript, but I don't get the for loop you have used. Could you point me to a document on this please?

Comment: this is an R `for` loop rather than a javascript one, some info [here](http://paleocave.sciencesortof.com/2013/03/writing-a-for-loop-in-r/)

Comment: thanks, but I was talking about the <pre>scroll(0,"i*10000,")</pre>  I've heard that the "scroll" command is used in Javascript (like this one: click, hover, etc). 2.- Why 'i*10000'? Is it: for every loop, scroll 10,000 pixels?

Comment: I tried doing the same code as above but it gives me "character(0)".. Why is it so??

Comment: this is now outdated, it appears to use Docker instead

Answer (score -1):

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://www.linio.com.co/c/celulares-y-tablets?page=1"
page<-html_session(url)

html_nodes(page,css=".price-secondary") %>% html_text()
```

Loop through the website `https://www.linio.com.co/c/celulares-y-tablets?page=2` and 3 and so on and it will be easy for you to scrape the data

EDIT dated 07/05/2019

The website elements changed. Hence new code

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://www.linio.com.co/c/celulares-y-tablets?page=1"
page<-html_session(url)

html_nodes(page,css=".price-main") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: lineo changed it's url structure, not, as you say, is easy to scrap their products. Not in 2015.

Comment: Yeah they have changed the css element alone. It still works with this code @OmarGonzales

`library(rvest)
url<-"https://www.linio.com.co/c/celulares-y-tablets?page=1"
page<-html_session(url)

html_nodes(page,css=".price-main") %>% html_text()`